# Ng build The ..\src\environments\environment.dev.ts path in file replacements does not exist

Tags: angular, angular7, ng-build

I'm trying to do `ng build --configuration=development` but it gives the following error:

> The
>   C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\src\environments\environment.dev.ts
>   path in file replacements does not exist. Error: The
>   C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\src\environments\environment.dev.ts
>   path in file replacements does not exist.
>       at Object.normalizeFileReplacements (C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\normalize-file-replacements.js:25:19)
>       at Object.normalizeBuilderSchema (C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\normalize-builder-schema.js:37:97)
>       at BrowserBuilder.run (C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js:31:33)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.getBuilderDescription.pipe.operators_1.concatMap.builder
>   [as project]
>   (C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:121:415)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:69:27)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:55:26)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>       at TapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:65:26)
>       at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
>       at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
>       at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:55:26)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)

In my `angular.json` file I have

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css",
              "src/assets/scss/material-dashboard.scss",
              "src/assets/css/demo.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.min.js",
              "node_modules/arrive/src/arrive.js",
              "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
              "node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js",
              "node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
```

I've checked the path and it is correct, the file is there. What is wrong?

Comment: do you have a file named `environment.dev.ts`?

Comment: Yes I have the file and it is in the path I've specified

Comment: Usually for development doesn't need to mention the environment params, do you specifically want to do that? so `ng build` will build dev for you, and doesn't need to have a file named `env...dev.ts`

Comment: can you confirm if you can open this path `C:\Users\Marina\Desktop\heliosFrontEnd_admin\src\environments\environment.dev.ts`

Answer (score 1):

After "configurations" you must see "serve".

Add development.

```
 "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "{your_project_name}:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "{your_project_name}:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "{your_project_name}:build:development"
            }
          }
        },
```